# Plot pixels time series

Tags: r, plot, time-series, raster

I'm trying to create an interactive plot of a raster brick, whereby clicking on a pixel gives you a time series of data at that pixel. (My raster brick is about 345 image.)

This is what I did:

```
library(raster)

EVI <- "D:\\Modis_EVI\\Original\\EVI_Stack_single5000.tif"
y.EVI <- brick(EVI)
plot(as.numeric(click(y.EVI)), type="l", lwd=2)
```

But it does not plot at all. And when i try with a smaller stack like 4 images only it gives this error:

```
 Error in plot.window(…) : need finite 'xlim' values
```

Any advice please?

Comment: Why would plotting a single value be meaningful with setting up a coordinate system and an x-value? Seems like you would first need to display the tif?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you only want to allow the user to click once, you should specify `n=1` in `click`. For example:

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(replicate(10, raster(matrix(runif(100), ncol=10))))

plot_ts <- function(x) {
  plot(x[[1]])
  z <- c(click(x, n=1, show=FALSE))
  plot(z, type='l', lwd=2, ylab='y', xlab='time', las=1)
  z
}

z <- plot_ts(b)
```

Here's an example plot after clicking a cell...
[image]